# getData() variable type

Tags: java, sockets

I have s simple UDP program where the server prints out the message from the client. However, if the client sends a phrase, in this case its "password", it should print another phrase ("123456").

However, when I send the string "password" using the client, the server does not recognise it and instead prints out "password".

May I know where I went wrong?

```
String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
            if(sentence == "password"){
                System.out.println("123456");
            }
            System.out.println(sentence);
```

Comment: Ah, hint: when you are so new to Java that you haven't learned that you use `equals()` to compare Strings, then seriously: writing code that does network communication is something you shouldn't worry about right now. Instead focus on learning these absolute essential basics ....

Answer (score 0):

Use the `string.equals(Object other)` method to compare strings, rather than the `==` operator